# Proving relation between related angles of two triangles given two constraints

Tags: geometry, triangles

I stumbled upon a theorem from My Instructor's geometry notes, it goes like

Consider two triangles ABC and PQR such that $\angle$ B=$\angle$ Q And Ratios $(BC/QR)=(CA/RP)$
Then
$\angle$ P=$\angle$ A or  $\angle$ p=180°-$\angle$ A

To prove I used similarity earlier, but failed

Edit: I was able to prove It using Sine law, I will Answer this question myself, any other ideas to prove the theorem will be great

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In My second Attempt I found That sine rule Helps in proving the above theoeam as follows

$BC=2R_1\sin(A)$ Where $R_1$ is circumradius of triangle (ABC)

$QR=2R_2\sin(P)$ Where $R_2$ is circumradius of triangle (PQR)

$AC=2R_1\sin(B)$ Where $R_1$ is circumradius of triangle (ABC)

$PR=2R_2\sin(Q)$ Where $R_1$ is circumradius of triangle (PQR)

now as $(BC/QR)=(AC/PR)$

It follows that

$R_1\sin(A)/R_2\sin(P)=R_1\sin(B)/R_2\sin(Q)$

Rearranging terms
and substituting $\sin(B)=\sin(Q)$ because  $\angle B=\angle Q$

we get sin(A)=sin(P)

as $\angle A$ and $\angle P$ are both less than 180 degrees,

It follows that
$\angle A$ = $\angle P $
or
$\angle A $=180°-$\angle P$

hence proved